# Python: Find maximum element index in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list

```
arr = [0, 1, 45, 2, 40, 3, 70, 4, 45, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

in which I'm trying to find the position/index of the maximum element from 3 consecutive elements using below code:

```
for i in range (0, len(arr)-3):
    print(arr.index(max(arr[i : i+3])))
```

When `i` goes to position 7, it gives incorrect result.

Result should be:

> 2 2 2 4 6 6 6 8 8 11 12

But is instead

> 2 2 2 4 6 6 6 2 2 11 12

Comment: What does "maximum element from 3 consecutive elements" mean? Is the result you show there correct, or incorrect? If incorrect, what should the result be? Please read [ask].

Comment: It's not really worth trying to do this in base Python. Pandas would be easier. See ^

Comment: result should be 2 2 2 4 6 6 6 8 8 11 12

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I'm kinda inclined to agree, but you've got a decent bit of rep from your answer :P I think the sliding window is easier to implement (and faster) using other tools, and the dupe status will prevent other answers that I _suspect_ will be sub-par

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because there's two `45`'s and `index` returns the first occurrence. You can pass a `start` and `end` argument to tell the `index` method from which indices to start looking from.

```
for i in range (0, len(arr)-3):
    print(arr.index(max(arr[i : i+3]), i, i+3))
```

Or alternatively:

```
for i in range (0, len(arr)-3):
    sliced_array = arr[i : i+3]
    print(i + sliced_array.index(max(sliced_array)))
```

Comment: Nice. The alternative, which I won't bother to post as a separate answer, is to save the slice (`arr[i:i+3]`) in a separate variable and do `i + the_slice.index(max(the_slice))`

Comment: @alaniwi True. I'll add that. Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, it shouldn't *need* that `end` argument. (Not that it does any harm.)

Comment: @alaniwi True, but having the end argument will reduce the amount of elements the index method have to compare

Comment: @TedKleinBergman It will tell it when to give up if it hasn't yet found a match, but it is already constrained to find a match before it gets to the point where it could give up.

Comment: @alaniwi Ahh, that's right. Didn't think about that